# Find all move constructors and move assignment operators (particularly those without 'noexcept')

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, move-semantics, std, noexcept

In Visual Studio 2017, I'm attempting to add 'noexcept' to all relevant move constructors and move assignment operators so that they can be called by Standard Library containers.

Is there a way to find all move constructors and move assignment operators?  Or is there a compiler warning to turn on if a move constructor/assignment operator is not flagged with 'noexcept'?

Comment: You should add some code, what kind of class are you creating, what are its uses?

Comment: Ideally you should have no user defined move constructors and move assignment operators, or close to none. You should follow the rule of 0.

Comment: Actually, I think searching for std::move being called is probably a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Simply look for them in your codebase:

```
grep -E '\(.*&&.*\)' | grep -v noexcept
```

You might need to improve this regexp in order to better filter matches. You can:

- take advantage that a move constructor, as all constructors, has no return type (`^\w*\W*\(`);
- take advantage that a move constructor takes exactly one argument (replace `.*` by `[^,]*`);
- filter only declarations or definitions looking for the final semi-colon.

Comment: @JoshGreifer I `didtexpect` a joke :D fixed